# Spotify API - JSON returns undefined, but I can still console.log() it

Tags: javascript, json, express, spotify

I'm trying to use Spotify's Web Player API to access the value 'device_id'.  According to the docs, the server-side API call I make should return a 'json payload that contains device objects' such as below:

**This is my API call:**

```
app.get('/c+party', (req,res)=>{
    const access_token = req.query.access_token;
    var device_id;
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/devices',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        json:true
    };
    request.get(options, (err,response,body) => {
        const device_id = body.devices[0].id;
        res.json(device_id);
    });
});
```

**It should return:**

```
{
  "devices" : [ {
    "id" : "5fbb3ba6aa454b5534c4ba43a8c7e8e45a63ad0e",
    "is_active" : false,
    "is_private_session": true,
    "is_restricted" : false,
    "name" : "My fridge",
    "type" : "Computer",
    "volume_percent" : 100
  } ]
}
```

**edit, here's the error:**

```
const device_id = body.devices[0].id;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Request._callback (C:\code\music-room\src\server.js:69:43)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\code\music-room\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\code\music-room\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\code\music-room\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

I can console.log(body) to see the desired output, but I can't actually *access* the value I want.  When my code runs, I get an error that body.devices is undefined. Any help with a fix?  I'm brand new with express.js - is my routing messing this up?

Another edit: I tried res.json(body)... my server is responding with an empty 'devices' array of objects.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `body` variable?

Comment: When I log the body variable, it appears exactly as expected (the JSON in my post)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending an empty response back from your API. That's what `res.end()` does. I am not entirely sure what is the content of the Spotify API response, but if you can see the correct JSON value in the `body` variable, you can use `res.json(...)` instead of `res.end()` like so:

```js
request.get(options, (err,response,body) => {
 // Assuming that the body variable contains the correct data
 const device_id = body.devices[0].id;
 res.json(device_id);
});
```

Comment: I've actually tried with res.json(), but end up with the same result.  I'm thinking that the problem lies with trying to assign the id to 'device_id' (even though I can log it to the console...).  I edited my post to share what I see.

Comment: Are you sure that the Spotify API responds with the correct data? From what I can tell, it doesn't return any devices.